# MessageExtension returned a NSURLErrorDomain when requesting the server

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

I'm developing iOS message extension to filter the unwanted message. The plugin needs a help from server to filter the message. However, the iOS returned the error `NSURLErrorDomain` while requesting the server.

Based on the [official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/sms_and_mms_message_filtering/creating_a_message_filter_app_extension), I have done the following steps:

- I added Associated Domains capability with value: `messagefilter:mydomain.io`
- I defined the key/value pair in `Info.plist` of Message Extension.
  `ILMessageFilterExtensionNetworkURL` has value: `https://mydomain.io/api/v1/sms`

The code that I test the request as follows:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://mydomain.io/api/v1/sms")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("you-value-goes-here", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
    if let data = data {
        print(data)
    } else if let error = error {
        print("Http failed: \(error)")
    }
}

task.resume()
```

From the stack trace, as far as I known, there is a problem with dns resolution. Why does this happened and how to fix this case?

```
[0] (null)  "_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey" : Int32(-72000)    
[1] (null)  "NSUnderlyingError" : domain: "kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork" - code: 18446744073709550613    
[2] (null)  "_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey" : "LocalDataTask <B496A974-7009-4FCE-BF45-FEC07BA1E8DF>.<1>" 
[3] (null)  "_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey" : 1 element  
[4] (null)  "NSLocalizedDescription" : "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the apple-app-site-association file to your server?

Comment: @Paulw11 not yet. Why is apple-app-site-association related to DNS query ?

Comment: The apple-app-site-association file is the key to enabling an associated domain.  The "Shared credentials" document linked to by the document you linked to describes setting up the site association file.  I imagine you get a DNS lookup because your extension operates in a sandboxed network environment and your server is not whitelisted

Comment: @Paulw11. Thank you for your information. I will try. Is there any method to generate the apple-app-site-association ? or I have to configure by myself based on the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains) ?